# How do i declare a variable in cypress that makes it available outside the function

Tags: variables, automation, cypress

So i have declared a variable outside a function as an empty string let content = "" and inside the function i have given it a value.  so i know that inside the function is working and updating the status but when i get to the last line it is failing with the following error message

cy.contains() cannot be passed an empty string.

Here is the code i am running

```
let content = "";
  //Check what the value of the status is and select another status value


cy.get('h3').contains("Financial Account Status Change").closest("form").find('span').eq(1).then((el) => {
            content = el.text();
            if (content == "00 (Active)") {
               cy.get('.modal-body > :nth-child(2) > .col-sm-9 > .form-control').select('05 (Decline)')   
            } else             {
            cy.get('.modal-body > :nth-child(2) > .col-sm-9 > .form-control').select('00 (Active)')
            } 
         });

        
      
  cy.get('.modal-body > :nth-child(3) > .col-sm-9 > .form-control').type('No Good Reason')
  cy.get('.modal-body > :nth-child(4) > .col-sm-9 > .form-control').type('Testing Memo')
  //Check the cancel button works
  cy.get('.btn').contains('Cancel').should('be.visible').click()
  //Check the status hasnt changed
  cy.get('.ng-binding > .ng-scope > .glyphicons').click()
```

This is the line its failing on

cy.get('.ng-binding').parents('.ng-scope').contains(content).should('be.visible')

Please could someone help me understand how i can declare the variable so it is available outside the function as i need to do this a few times

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wrap your variable and get it elsewhere. You can try

```
cy.get('h3').contains("Financial Account Status Change").closest("form").find('span').eq(1).then((el) => {
     content = el.text();
     ...
     return cy.wrap(content).as('MyCustomContent')
         });
```

And after

```
cy.get('@MyCustomContent').then(content=>{
   cy.get('.ng-binding').parents('.ng-scope').contains(content).should('be.visible')
})
```

Comment: ok i tried your suggestion and am getting the following error Timed out retrying after 4000ms: Expected to find content: '@MyCustomContent' within the element: <span.ng-binding> but never did.  do you know why.  thank you for your help

Comment: I now need to pass the same variable between two functions declared like this.  Would you know how that works.                                            it("Account Details Status OK button works",() =>{
    login();
    access_financial_enquiry();
    check_f_e_overview_account_details_status_modal_ok();
    })
    it("Account Details Status is updated",() =>{
      login();
      access_financial_enquiry();
      check_f_e_overview_account_details_status_modal_isupdated();  @Wandrille  would you know how it works

Comment: I invite you to create a new question :) Otherwise, it would be more complex to help.

Comment: yeah im missing information.  ok will do thank you for your help

Comment: ive added another question, if you could help that would be great.  here is a link.  its kind of related to this question  @Wandrille ://stackoverflow.com/questions/76093092/how-do-i-declare-a-variable-inside-one-function-and-pass-it-to-another-function